# Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. If $||T(x)|| = ||x||$, then $T$ is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Theorem: Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$.  If $\|T(x)\| = \|x\|$ for all $x\in V$, then $T$ is onto.

We can easily show that $ker(T) = {0}$, thus $T$ is one-to-one. Then since T is a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces of equal dimensions, one-to-one implies that it is also onto.

**However, I want to try to approach this directly from the definition of onto.** This is what I got at the moment: Since $$||T(x)|| = ||x|| \ \forall  x \in V$$, so $$T(x) = x \ or \  T(x) = -x$$ Then $$x = T(x)\  or\  x = -T(x)$$, satisfying $\forall y \in V, \exists x \in V s.t. T(x)=y$.

I'm really not sure if the 2nd method is correct, so if not, maybe someone can point it out, and show a way to do it directly.

Comment: $$\|T(x)\|=\|x\| \kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies T(x) = \pm x$$  Consider a rotation by $90^\circ$.

Comment: @TonyTarng I edited your question to hopefully make it more explicit that $(1)$ you're assuming that $T:V\to V$, and $(2)$ you're asking for a proof that doesn't involve using the fact that $T$ is one-to-one.  If you don't like the edit, feel free to rollback.

Comment: @Bye_World I think your edit is great. Much clearer than my original question. Thanks!

Comment: @Bye_World Hmmm, yes I see my mistake there. I still hope to see a method of doing it directly though.

Comment: @TonyTarng I am not sure how much direct you want. One way I come up with, is proving that $T(v_1), \ldots , T(v_n)$ are linearly independent, where $v_1, \ldots , v_n$ form a basis for $V$. Then $T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_n)$ also form a basis for $V$. Thus, any vector can be represented as a linear combination of $T(v_1),\ldots , T(v_n)$. But, this would be essentially the same as your first proof.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume that $V$ is finite dimensional, and that $T$ is a map from $V$ to $V$ the answer is positive. In "every other" case, the answer is negative: a map $T:V\to W$ between normed spaces that preserves norms --- that is, an isometry --- needn't be surjective, but it is always injective. A simple example is the inclusion in one coordinate of $V$ into $V\oplus V$ where, given a norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ in $V$, we endow $V\oplus V$ with the norm $\lVert (v,w)\rVert = \lVert v\rVert +\lVert w\rVert$.

Comment: And if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then a norm-preserving operator $T \colon V \to V$ need not be surjective either.